# Laravel4 - Trying to create widget like partials that will pass/accept a parameter to get the correct data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Within my views I am trying to reuse a partials, so I can create a list of latest posts anywhere in the site / sidebar by using the blade @include where the passed variable is the number of posts to be included, like this:

```
@include('widgets.lastestposts', array('numPosts' => '10')
```

*However the problem I have is how to get the Post data for the correct number of posts within the partial?*

I could pass through a list of all posts via Post::all() using the controller or even a View::composer and then within the partial use a @for|@endfor loop to only show the correct number based on the 'numPosts' value.

However this doesn't feel right and I am sure there must be a better way than pulling a complete list of Posts when I may only need 5 or 10.

I tried View::composers but I could find how to pass through a variable so I can get the correct number of Posts returned.  I can't access the parameter 'numPosts' via

```
$view->getdata()
```

as I expect 'numPosts' needs to be passed to the view via the controller, rather than the Blade file - either that or I messed up!

Am I missing something easy here or is what I am looking to do actually a very bad idea and I should be doing something else?

Any pointers are most gratefully received. Thanks!

(ps - I was looking to be able to do this via the blade file rather than setting up the number of posts in the controller to allow our designers/HTML coders to simply add the widgets and parameters to the views rather than have to mess with controllers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using View Composers. You can pass data to the composer with your include:

```
@include('widgets.lastestposts', array('numPosts' => '10')
```

and then from within the view composer you should be able to access that param like so:

```
View::composer('widgets.latestposts', function($view)
{
   $view_data= $view->getData();
   $post_count = $view_data['numPosts'];

   //You will have to implement something to do this
   $post_data = Post::getLatestPosts($post_count);
```

and then you can pass the post data back with:

```
   $view->with('posts', $post_data);
}
```

and then from within your blade partial widgets.latestposts you can iterate over $posts to display the posts.

I know you said in your post that you tried this method, but I am fairly certain that this approach should work. Double check all your filenames, file extensions (.blade.php) etc...

Hope this works.

Comment: Your code is 95% what I'd done and given up on!  However your conviction made me check **everything** again and so I realised I'd created the View Composer on the main page calling the widget NOT on the widget page. Hence why `view->getdata()` wasn't returning anything. When I changed it to `View::Composer('widgets.latestposts')` it all worked as I needed.  Thanks for your help and making me realise I wasn't going insane.

Answer (score 1):

Using a view composer is pretty easy:

You can, for instance, store your number of posts in a Session var:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('numPosts', Session::get('numPosts'));
}
```

Or just hardcode them:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('numPosts', 10);
}
```

And use it in your view:

```
<?php $i=1; ?>

@foreach($posts as $post) 
  {{ $post->title }}

  <?php 
      $i++; 
      if ($i > $numPosts) break;
  ?>          
@endforeach
```

Assuming that you've passed $posts to your view:

```
$posts = Post::all();

return View::make('your-view')->with('posts', $posts);
```

But, remember, you also can do things like

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(Session::get('numPosts'))->get();

// or

$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();

// and

return View::make('your-view')->with('posts', $posts);
```

So you won't have to filter them again in your view.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination and variations. Whilst it was not quite what I was looking for in this scenario, use of the session variable is something I'd not considered, but is what I've now got in mind for something else in the project!  So Thanks a million for your idea.